# problem with sql query

Tags: c#, sql

I have this code to query the database:

```
for (int kk = 1; kk < search.Length; kk++)
{
    where +=  " and keyword like '%"+search[kk]+";%'";
    OleDbCommand sqlcmd = new OleDbCommand(
      "select id,name,address,keyword from table1 where  keyword like '%"+search[0]+"%' " + 
      where + "  order by name", sqlconConnection);
    sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    OleDbDataReader sdaRes = sqlcmd0.ExecuteReader();
    while (sdaRes.Read())
    {
        thumbnails_id[recordcount] = sdaRes.GetInt32(3);
        recordcount++;
    }

    sdaResult0.Close();

}
```

When i execute this query in access it return the result but when i run it in the application it run but does not show any result.

the structure of the table is:

The DB table look like this:

```
id   name   keyword  File  Fkey
1     a      yellow;  c:/   20
2     a      blue;    c:/   20
3     a      Pinky;   c:/   20
4     b      blue;  c:/   21
5     b      Redish;  c:/   21
6     c      yellow;  c:/   22
7     c      blue;    c:/   22
8     c      Pinky;   c:/   22
9     c      orange;  c:/   22
10    c      Redish;  c:/   22
```

what the search query is meant to be like this:
`select * from this table1 where name like variable and variable two and variable three` and so on. So when user type suppose orange all result should come then when user type in after orange Pinky then orange and pinky result should comes on. but I do not know what is wrong in the code although i get no error or no Warning message.

Comment: Please, please, please read up on Sql Query Injection and Parameterized Queries, especially if this is going to be exposed on the internet.

Comment: @Talljoe Thanks i was testing it just this way,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `OR` instead of `AND` because keyword cannot be at the same time 'red' and 'blue' and etc...

Comment: Also needs `GROUP BY`, `HAVING` and `COUNT` I think (if they are trying to bring back `name`s that have both red and blue rows)

Comment: @Christian Boariu, this and work fine in the access but in code do not work and if i put OR then i will get a 1000 of records. so i need and to shrink the result with the keyword.

Comment: @Safi Can you put the query you run in access? I have doubts that it runs fine with AND

Comment: @safi - I may have guessed wrong but think you might need something like `SELECT name, File, FKey FROM table1 WHERE  keyword like '%yellow%' or  keyword like '%blue%' 
GROUP BY name, File, FKey HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT keyword)=2`

Comment: @Christian Boariu in access it look like this: `select * from table1 where keyword like  'red;' And 'blue;'` and the result is what i want. means run perfect.

Comment: @Safi Pay attention that there are some minor differences between Access sql and SQL ANSI. Is this working ok? 'select * from table1 where keyword like 'red;' And keyword like 'blue;'

Comment: @Christian Boariu no, i tested your query now it is now working, but this query work.  ` select * from table1 where keyword like 'red;' And 'blue;' `

Comment: @Safi Yes, As I supposed it's not working so Access considers your syntax differently ('And something' it's working in access but not in SQL) but in SQL it's for sure you need OR as I said and not AND.

Comment: @Cristian Boariu i am using access 2007 so what i need to do?

Comment: @Safi: When you test in Access you need to write the syntax of the sql query correctly like in SQL (if something is running it does not implicitly means that it's correct) so if you put OR in your access query it will work, thus you need it in sql from C# too.

Comment: @Christian I was looking it in the wrong way, it was quite useful. I Changed `where + = "and keyword ...." to where += "and ....` took out the keyword which solved the problem actually the query was looking right but access was not accepting it and returning null.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (sdaRes.Read())
{
    thumbnails_id[recordcount] = sdaResult0.GetInt32(3);
    recordcount++;
}
```

Either this is a typo or you are not really reading the results from the reader you are using from your query, also  id is the first column, so imo it should be:

```
while (sdaRes.Read())
{
    thumbnails_id[recordcount] = sdaRes.GetInt32(0);
    recordcount++;
}
```

Comment: I am reading the result from the reader you can see in the code,you mean to say i should also include this id i.e First COlumn of the table?

Comment: @safi: where is `sdaResult0` defined in your code? Either your code samples is incomplete or wrong

Comment: @BorkenGlass I just mistype the name from sdaRes to sdaResult0

Comment: @safi: You've mistyped it in another place (`sdaResult0.Close();`) as well as you've probably mistyped this: `sqlcmd0.ExecuteReader();` (shouldn't it be `sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();`?).